# Boolean value not updating Flask-SQLAlchemy with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

```
try:
        user_.current_test_id = db_obj.id
        user_.currect_test_active = True
        db.session.add(user_)
        db.session.commit()
        
    except Exception as error:
        print("error")
        db.session.rollback()

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "User"
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
     current_test_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Test.id', name="FK__Test_User"))
   current_test_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

When I run the try and except code, the user_.current_test_id gets updated correctly but the user_.current_test_active still stays False. Why is this happening ?

Comment: By "PSQL" do you mean "PostgreSQL"?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes

Comment: Is `user_` an existing entry that you have retrieved from the database using `.select()`, `.query()`, `.get()`, or similar? How is it related to `db_obj`?

Comment: yes, I got user_ using User.query.filter_by(id=session["user_id"]).first()
db_obj.id is another integer.

Comment: Update, I changed the class to have store current_test_active as an integer, but it still won't update the value. This is absolutely bizzare

Comment: NVM, resolved, the error was the name was spelled incorrectly